# Correct way to test if a User model has a password

Tags: python, django

I have this models

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class Account(AbstractUser):
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=False, null=False)


class User(Account):
    security_question = models.TextField(blank=True)
    security_answer = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
```

and this simple test case:

```
from django import test
from myapp import models


class UserTestCase(test.TestCase):

    def test_user_password_cannot_be_empty(self):
        def create_user_without_password():
            models.User.objects.create(
                username='usr2',
                first_name='Name',
                last_name='Name2',
                email='me@email.com'
        )

        # should throw an error
        self.assertRaises(
            Exception,
            create_user_without_password
        )
```

The test should pass as password is a mandatory field, yet by running `python manage.py test --pattern="tests_*.py"` I get

> ======================================================================
>
> FAIL: test_user_password_cannot_be_empty (myapp.tests_user_testcase.UserTestCase)
>   AssertionError: Exception not raised by create_user_without_password

---

I guess I'm testing it wrongly. What is the correct way?

---

Specs:

- Python 3.6.1
- Django 2.1.1
- Windows 10

Comment: Why do you think this should raise an exception? What is enforcing that in the code itself?

Comment: Also, you are not calling the function at all: `create_user_without_password` should be `create_user_without_password()`

Comment: Your test appears to be working, and `password` is not required(or `blank=True`). If you can't figure out how to make your test pass, then we need the `Model` code that has the `password` field.

Comment: I'm not sure you are running you assertion correctly either. I believe you should use `with self.assertRaises(Exception): (indent your next line) create_user_without_password()`

Comment: @CarlBrubaker I'm probably misusing the `self.assertRaises` function. Just digging more into it then I will get back to you. The base model containing the pwd is what you see in the code: django's built-in `AbstractUser` and thus `AbstractBaseUser`

Comment: @DanielRoseman Just assuming. E.g. creating an object with an already-existing PK raises an error. Thus I imagined it should be acting similarly in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into the nature that Django Models will save `blank=False` fields without error. You can find lengthy debates about it. To enforce it at the `model.save` level, you have to overwrite the save method.

```py
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.full_clean()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Great insights by both you and @dirkgroten. I'm marking your answer as correct as your snippet helped me get closer to what I am try to achieve

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, but `password` is a `CharField` so you're always able to create a user without a password this way (`CharField` gets always set to empty string by default even if `blank=False`).

You are also correctly calling `self.assertRaises`, which takes a *callable*. So it would be wrong to do `self.assertRaises(Exception, create_user_without_password())` because that would indeed raise an exception because your function would be called twice: the exception would be NoneType is not callable. Your test would pass, but not for the correct reason!

The default Django model `AbstractBaseUser` doesn't force `password` to be set. The forms to create a user do this. The reason is, you may have a system where users are first created by other users without password so they can set the password themselves.